# How do I pass a nested class from the View to the Controller for post processing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-controller

So I have a pretty simplistic requirement. I'm trying to allow an edit page for my User Model, but the User Model references a UserTypeModel which basically dictates (Admin/Regular/Super/etc). I'm trying to populate in the Edit view a Combo Box for selection of what User Type they should be. See my code below:

```
public class UserModel : BaseModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public UserTypeModel UserType { get; set; }

}

public class UserTypeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Those are my Models. These are fetched out of a database, so in my Controller I create a List of all possible UserTypeModels and send them over to the View along with the actual UserModel. See Controller code below:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int pId = 0)
{
    UserModel vUserModel = fMySqlService.GetUser(pId);

    List<UserTypeModel> vUserTypes = new List<UserTypeModel>(fMySqlService.GetAllUserTypes());
    SelectList vSelectList = new SelectList(vUserTypes, "Id", "Name", vUserModel.UserType);
    ViewBag.UserTypesList = vSelectList;

    return View(vUserModel);
}
```

As you can see above, I am getting the specific UserModel to edit (this also populates the correct UserTypeModel with all attributes id/name/description). I then create a list of all possible UserTypeModels and send this over via the ViewBag.

And now for the last piece, the edit View Code. I think this is where I suck the most...

```
@model Project.Models.UserModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>UserModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserType.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("UserType_Id", ViewBag.UserTypesList as SelectList)
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

So as you can see I am creating a DDL with the Id/Name of "UserType_Id" and pulling out my list from the ViewBag.UserTypesList. Ideally what I would like to happen is:

1. SelectedValue is not set properly first off. I've read a bunch of issues around this and I'm still not sure how to resolve mine. I'd like this to be pre-populated with the List correctly.
2. As the user changes the SelectedValue in the DDL, I'd like my Model to come back to the Controller and have the correct property set in Model.UserType.Id, but Model.UserType comes back as null.

I won't bother posting the code for the Post of the Edit, just know that the parameters are:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserModel pUserModel)
```

Comment: I may have just answered my own question, but before marking it I want to get others opinions. I've modified the DDL to this: @Html.DropDownList("UserType.Id", ViewBag.UserTypesList as SelectList) and the selected value is there correctly and now my Controller recieves Model.UserType.Id correctly (other values are blank though such as Model.UserType.Name..How do I pass that too?

Comment: You would have to use hidden fields and some AJAX most likely, but before you run off and do that, don't. You shouldn't post the whole selected model -- just the id. In your POST action, you use the id to look up the model *fresh* from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Chris, I agree 100%. I didn't even bother trying to pass the additional information as the only bit I needed was the Id for my DB operation.